# What transport protocols are supported in Windows 10?

Tags: tcp, windows-10, udp, sctp, dccp

Obviously TCP/UDP are supported in Windows but are there any other transport protocols? I know that SCTP and DCCP exist but cant seem to find any reference to them with regards to their support in Windows OSes and only managed to find third party drivers but none seem to be past Windows 7. Is the lack of support due to lack of use or another reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mostly used traport layer network protocols are tcp and udp yes
TCP (1981), UDP (1980)

Stream Control Transmission Protocol aka SCTP (2007) combines TCP and UDP, reliable as tcp, uses datagrams like in UDP and supports multiple parallel streams of chunks

[SCTP RFC4960](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4340.txt)

Datagram Congestion Control Protocol aka DCCP (2006) provides bidirectional unicast connections of congestion-controlled unreliable datagrams.

[DCCP RFC4340](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4340.txt)

Edit: the following is the conclusion of a paper written while back

> Adding multihoming and mobility support to Internet transport
> protocols changes the environment in which transport-layer security
> mechanisms operate. This may cause non-cryptographic security
> mechanisms, such as TCP sequence numbers and SCTP verification tags,
> to break. The attacker may be able to spoof data and signaling
> messages and hijack connections. Dynamic multi-addressing also gives
> raise to new types of attacks such as address squatting, redirection
> of data from a server to the target of a bombing attack, and
> connection forwarding. In this paper, we describe a number of such
> attacks against SCTP and suggest low-cost changes to the protocol
> specification and implementations. Several SCTP implementations were
> found to be vulnerable to all or most of the attacks described in this
> paper. Table 1 summarizes the main protocol weaknesses, attacks and
> solutions and how they relate to each other. (Some attacks depend on
> multiple vulnerabilities, which is indicated by multiple crosses in
> the column. We have also marked the changes that should be made
> immediately to the implementations.) The lessons from our security
> analysis apply to other transport protocols and to practically any
> multihoming or mobility solution that uses end-to-end signaling.

you can find the paper [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2004/05/aura-nikander-camarillo-ssp04.pdf)

Comment: this doesn't address the question. Are SCTP and DCCP supported by Windows 10? Windows 10 is not an "older system".

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand what those protocols are being used for, by reading the rfc. none of these 2 protocols are supported from ms windows 10 version. I think microsoft doesn't want to

Comment: Again, as I'm relatively intimately familiar with these protocols: I'm asking for the state of operating system support in Windows 10. The paper you added is interesting, but considering the wide-spread support in other operating system a relatively moot point. Also, unrelated to the question of *whether or not SCTP is a operating system feature of Win10*. So, if you'd add "Windows 10 does **not** support SCTP", that would actually answer the question, but then I'd have to ask you how specifically it doesn't support it, since LinuxKit/WSL2 under Win10 does.

Comment: well I stated all that because you posed two questions, the second being "if there is a lack of support due to lack of use or another reason". the answer for the first question "What transport protocols are supported in Windows 10?" is TCP and UDP (wrong use of the word "mostly" there)

Comment: ah, OK, but that is only a marginal answer, seeing that, as said, at least in WSL2, which I'd argue is part of Windows, there's a working SCTP socket type!

Comment: of course there are third party implementations as you mentioned on your post, even running on windows. you can also write your own implementation. I assumed you were looking for explanations about native support

Comment: WSL2/LinuxKit is not a "third party implementation". It's literally part of the Windows OS, written and maintained by Microsoft, and offers an execution layer, just like the Win9x, WinNT and POSIX layers you already get without WSL

Comment: it is a docker. third party, not native, in fact it is a real linux lernel running from a very lightweight vm

Comment: Ah interesting! WSL1 was indeed a subsystem, WSL2 is a virtualized kernel with a couple of interfaces to the host, which *probably* means Windows is just passing the raw IP packet down to the Linux kernel. Nice, thank you! I've learned a lot today.

Comment: I am glad I helped you

Answer (score 0):

I will not claim a prize, but I would like to share my experience in the field of network packages. I recently started learning the Scapy tool written in Python. With the help of this tool, I was able to more clearly and clearly understand the work of network packets and, moreover, understand how they work and are supported. This tool helped me a lot. Maybe he will give you some answers to your questions.

```
>>> ls(SCTP)
sport      : ShortField                          = (None)
dport      : ShortField                          = (None)
tag        : XIntField                           = (None)
chksum     : XIntField                           = (None)
>>> a=SCTP()
>>> a.show()
###[ SCTP ]### 
  sport= None
  dport= None
  tag= None
  chksum= None
```